# Is it possible to perform operation on date field in email alert via workflow?

Tags: email, workflow, email-alert

I want to perform  operation on custom date field to get the completion year.Is it possible on **email template creation** ?

Comment: You should try next scenario - visualforce emawil template + email component with controller, that do some dml, or start future method etc

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: @MahimaGandhe I want  out of the box feature to in email template feature to calculate difference between two dates at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in an out of the box way if you want to do so.. you need to hold one more field in your object which will give you the number of years between two dates. Then you will be able to merge that field in your email template.

[Please refer](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h1s9AAA)

Hope that will help you.